# Display Leading Zeros On Input Number Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two `input` fields representing hours and minutes.

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="24" step="1" value="00" class="hours">
<input type="number" min="0" max="0.60" step="0.01" value="00" class="minutes">
```

Which display as:

```
0:0
```

Or:

```
5:3
```

Is there a way to display it as:

```
00:00
```

Or:

```
05:03
```

i.e in 24-hour data format (before people suggest it, I can't use type="time").

Comment: Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638018/current-time-formatting-with-javascript.  It's not exactly what you're doing but the JavaScript formatting for hours and minutes should work.

Comment: duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684737/force-leading-zero-in-number-input

Comment: Actually this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add an *onchange* attribute to your input tag, which calls a javascript function.

```
    <script>
       function myFunction() {
           var minuteValue = document.getElementById("minutes").value;
           if (minuteValue.length < 2) {
               minuteValue = "0" + minuteValue;
           }
           alert(minuteValue);
       }
    </script>

    <input id="minutes" onchange="myFunction()"/>
```

Comment: You don't need to call `toString()` because the value already comes as a string. Bonus tidbit: you can call `thatElement.valueAsNumber` to get it as a number, if you need that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Answer (score 1):

```
 function formatNums(num){
   if (nums < 10){
     return "0" + num;
   }
 }

 var formattedHours = formatNums(hours);
 var formattedMinutes = formatNums(minutes);
```

---

**NOTE:** This method uses `type="text"` so be sure to convert back to a number if needed. `Number(formattedHours);`

Comment: That makes no sense. You can't have a `number` with preceding zeros.

Comment: @Andy Use text when displaying the number and convert to number when you need to use it for calculations

Comment: Doesn't setting the type to text get rid of any platform specific way for entering numbers? (e.g. in a desktop browser it shows an up/down bar to increment and decrement the number

Answer (score 1):

Add a leading zero with a JavaScript function.

```js
const hours = document.getElementById("hours");
const minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");

function addLeadingZero(value) {
  return value.length < 2 ? "0" + value : value;
}

hours.addEventListener("input", function() {
  hours.value = addLeadingZero(hours.value);
});

minutes.addEventListener("input", function() {
  minutes.value = addLeadingZero(minutes.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="24" value="00" id="hours" class="hours">
<input type="number" min="0" max="59" value="00" id="minutes" class="minutes">
```

Answer (score 0):

simple is the best

```js
`${number}`.padStart(2, '0')
```