# How to show zero after number in input?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a input and I need to show : 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09

But default is this: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force leading zero in number input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684737/force-leading-zero-in-number-input)

Comment: I need Javascript code.....

Comment: Refer to this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043026/javascript-format-number-to-have-2-digit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native way of doing this, but you could listen to the input event on the text box, and pad the leading '0' every time the value changes.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("txtNum");
input.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.padStart(2,'0');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <input id="txtNum" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">

</body>
</html>
```