# Can I pad number with zeros in HTML <input type="number" />?

Tags: html, html-input

I have input for entering hours. To make it clear for the user that the number is an hour, I want to pad single digit hours with leading zero, e.g. show "02" instead of "2". Is that possible with HTML `<input type="number" />`? When I give it `value="02"` it renders `2` instead of `02`. So far the only solution I found is using `<input type="text" />` instead.

Comment: javascript. no native html or css way to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force leading zero in number input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684737/force-leading-zero-in-number-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the HTML5 definitions there is no option for specifying a format for the number. Nowadays latest browsers do not treat the number input the same anyway (see "Known issues" at https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number).

I fear the only option to force a given pattern in the input involves JavaScript.

Sources: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number, https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#number-state-typenumber, https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-floating-point-number

Comment: And how do you do it by JavaScript?

Comment: It seems it's not possible even with JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650932/set-value-to-currency-in-input-type-number